# Python pandas - yahoo finance isn't providing GOOG's historical prices?

Tags: python, pandas, yahoo-finance

Can someone please elaborate on why yahoo suddenly stopped giving GOOG's historical prices? [GOOG's historicla prices page](http://finance.yahoo.com/q/hp?s=GOOG) isn't very helpful either.
Code I used to check: (AAPL works, GOOG doesn't)

```
import pandas.io.data as web
import datetime

print web.get_data_yahoo('AAPL', datetime.datetime(2010,1,1), datetime.datetime(2013,12,31))['Adj Close']
print web.get_data_yahoo('GOOG', datetime.datetime(2010,1,1), datetime.datetime(2013,12,31))['Adj Close']
```

Comment: It's a market thing: Google made their old Class A shares switch to GOOGL, with new class C (nonvoting) shares taking over the old name GOOG.  Prior to April, old GOOG shares are actually what is now called GOOGL.